# Wrong codomain, why is this function called a composition?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, notation

I'm reading a book and it says:

> *Definition:* Let $\pmb f: \mathcal D_{\pmb f} \subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ and $\pmb g:\mathcal D_{\pmb g} \subset\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^p$ be two maps and $\pmb x_0\ \in  \mathcal D_{\pmb f}$ a point such that $\pmb y_0=\pmb f(\pmb x_0)\in \mathcal D_{\pmb g}$, so that the composite
> $$
> \pmb h=\pmb g \circ \pmb f : \mathcal D_{\pmb h} \subset \mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R^p \tag 1
> $$
> for $\pmb x_0\in \mathcal D_h$, is well defined.

So far so good! And then:

> *Theorem:*  Let $\pmb f$ be differentiable at $\pmb x_0 \in \mathcal D_{\pmb h}$ and $\pmb g$ differentiable at
> $\pmb y_0 = \pmb f(\pmb x_0)$. Then $\pmb h = \pmb g\circ \pmb f$ is differentiable at $\pmb x_0$ and its Jacobian matrix is
> $$
> \pmb J(\pmb g\circ \pmb f) (\pmb x_0) = \pmb J\pmb g(\pmb y_0)\pmb J\pmb f(\pmb x_0) \tag 2
> $$

So far so good! But then this example is given:

> Let $\phi: I\subset \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable map and $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ a scalar differentiable function. The composite $h(x)= f(x,\phi(x))$ is differentiable on $I$, and
> $$
> h'(x) = \frac{dh}{dx}(x)=
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,\phi(x))+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,\phi(x))\phi'(x) \tag 3
> $$
> as follows from the theorem above, since $h=f \circ \Phi$, with $\Phi:I\to \mathbb R^2$, $\Phi(x)=(x,\phi(x))$

Note: The book used $\Phi$ and not $\phi$ in the last line, is it a typo?

Here is my problem: I don't follow why $h$ is a composition of $f$ and $\phi$. Because, according to $(1)$ the co-domain of the "inner function", $\pmb f$, should be equal to the domain of the "outer function", $\pmb g$. But, in this example, the "inner function" is $\phi$ with the co-domain $I\subset \mathbb R$ and this is not equal to the domain of the "outer function", $f$, which is $\mathbb R^2$. So why is $h$ a composition?

Can somebody shed some light here?

Comment: The point is that you can’t compose $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\phi : I \to \mathbb{R}$ because the latter has the wrong codomain. That is precisely the reason why the book defines this new function $\Phi : I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which has the right codomain.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the map $x \mapsto (x, \phi(x))$ and call it $\Phi $, then you have that $h = f \circ \Phi$.

Comment: In fact, the book calls it $\Phi$ instead of $g.$

Comment: Yes, I'll change it.

Comment: Hi @PierreCarre! Is $\Phi$ itself a composition? An example: Say I have $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, $f(u,v)=u^2-v\sin u$ and $g:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, $g(x,y)=(x+y,xe^y)$ The composition is $$(f\circ g)(x,y)=f(x+y,xe^y)=(x+y)^2-xe^y\sin(x+y)$$ However, the composition $g\circ f$ is not valid. Can I introduce a function, say $F$ (corresponding to $\Phi$ in my post?)? If so, what is the domain and co-domain of $F$? Is it $F(a,b)=(a,b,f(a,b))=(a,b,a^2-b\sin a)$?